# What does "to scale" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From the movie "Atomic Blonde" (2017)

In the movie, there's a news report about Berliners destroying the Berlin Wall. The reporter says:

> East Berliners are overcome as they cross the border that has been
>   closed to them for 28 years. West Berliners are chipping away at the
>   wall that scarred their city and **scaling it.**

What does "slacing it" mean in this context?

Comment: See meaning 17: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scale?s=t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To climb. "We spent our summer scaling cliffs along the coast". To me there is a connotation of vertical surfaces, you might scale a cliff or wall but not a tree.

Comment: Hello,  welfare. If you would like to prosper here, might I suggest that you take the tour, and discover what is considered to be a proper question, and a good answer.